# Pyspark, Removing lines from a subset with nulls, save them and then adding them again

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

So here it is, basically I have something like this:

```
   C1   C2   C3    C4
a   0    1    null  4
b   0    1    3     4
c   0    1    4     4
d   0    null 5     4
```

So as far as removing goes, I've done it like this and it worked:

```
sub=['C2','C3']
df = df.na.drop(subset=sub)

   C1   C2   C3   C4
b   0    1    3    4
c   0    1    4    4
```

But now I would actually like to save those rows with nulls on another dataframe so I can add them later with some function.

```
Dataframe_of_nulls:
   C1   C2   C3   C4
a   0    1    null 4
d   0    null 5    4
```

Feel free to ignore the indexes, they are just so the expanation is less confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll can filter for each condition:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit
from operator import or_ 
from functools import reduce


def split_on_null(df, subset):
    any_null = reduce(or_, (col(c).isNull() for c in subset), lit(False))
    return df.where(any_null), df.where(~any_null)
```

Usage:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 1, None, 4), (0, 1, 3, 4), (0, 1, 4, 4), (0, None, 5, 4), 
    (0, 1, 3, 4), (0, None, 5, 4)]
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")

with_nulls, without_nulls = split_on_null(df, sub)
with_nulls.show()
```

```
+---+----+----+---+
| c1|  c2|  c3| c4|
+---+----+----+---+
|  0|   1|null|  4|
|  0|null|   5|  4|
|  0|null|   5|  4|
+---+----+----+---+
```

```py
without_nulls.show()
```

```
+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4|
+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  3|  4|
|  0|  1|  4|  4|
|  0|  1|  3|  4|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Alternative solution is to `subtract`:

```
without_nulls_ = df.na.drop(subset=sub)
with_nulls_ = df.subtract(without_nulls_ )
```

but it is way more expensive and won't preserve duplicates:

```
without_nulls_.show()
```

```
+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3| c4|
+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  3|  4|
|  0|  1|  4|  4|
|  0|  1|  3|  4|
+---+---+---+---+
```

```py
with_nulls_.show()
```

```
+---+----+----+---+                                                             
| c1|  c2|  c3| c4|
+---+----+----+---+
|  0|null|   5|  4|
|  0|   1|null|  4|
+---+----+----+---+
```